# Difficulty and total difficulty

Tags: blocks, difficulty

This is the info of one of the blocks in my private blockchain:

```json
{
  difficulty: 759585,
  extraData: "0xd783010409844765746887676f312e362e32856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0xcf3366fbf4b6c9adf63386b1cc1ed03957df28c57f576a5a4ceef4041011d0c0",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x37e5a459dbd48d4d9874e13cc334dab30373cece",
  nonce: "0x40f805725d02472c",
  number: 17000,
  parentHash: "0xaeb4da768e9e9cb4838e37128ffe895a2f8a684bf2a66339659bbb25a6e44a69",
  receiptRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 537,
  stateRoot: "0x8e61e87fbe4df30634472018ffb7c3f7a8315901ace91f9244958e067bf84a6b",
  timestamp: 1467943085,
  totalDifficulty: 10000790891,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
```

In this, what does the `difficulty` and the `totalDifficulty` parameters mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are explained on the wiki in the [JSON RPC README](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC), under the entry for [`eth_getBlockByHash()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbyhash).

> difficulty: QUANTITY - integer of the difficulty for this block.
>
> totalDifficulty: QUANTITY - integer of the total difficulty of the
>   chain until this block.

[ Where the difficulty itself is a measure of how difficult it is for a miner to mine a new block by finding a hash below a given target. An explanation of the calculations used to set Ethereum's difficulty can be found in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/how-is-the-mining-difficulty-calculated-on-ethereum) previous thread. ]

Comment: Current documentation link: https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getblockbyhash

Answer (score 8):

As Richard already pointed out, the difficulty is the *current* quantitative measure how hard it is to brute force ('mine') a block.

The total difficulty is the accumulated sum of all blocks difficulty till the block you queried. I recently learned, this is the best indicator for the longest chain, i.e., for a client to determine in case of a fork which chain to stick to. It will stick to the chain with the highest total difficulty.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. In case there was a fork of one block, is it not possible for both the valid blocks to have the same `totalDifficulty`?

Comment: Exactly, that's where the [uncles kick in](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/34/87).